# Database/Excel import and export format

Tags: database, vba, excel

We have a database program that can export and import excel sheets. The excel sheets it exports are formatted as text, I've noticed you cannot change the formatting in these exports without performing text to columns on the data first.

When I edit an export for import or create a new import file I format the cells as text but it doesn't upload nicely. It rounds numbers and skips some data.

I would like to know how to format the import file the same as the export file but I am not familiar with what kind of format behaves the way I described. I've written a bit of VBA to create the import file from data in a workbook so applying the formatting in VBA would be ideal. Any insight would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is the 'database program'?  If this is an old legacy tool, you may not have many, or any options.  If it is Access, you can write some VBA to format the exported Excel report.

```
'This deals with Excel already being open or not
On Error Resume Next
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If xl Is Nothing Then
  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

Set XlBook = GetObject(filename)
'filename is the string with the link to the file ("C:/....blahblah.xls")

'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
xl.Visible = True
XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
'xl.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75

'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet
Set xlsheet1 = XlBook.Worksheets(1)

'Then have some fun!
with xlsheet1
    .range("A1") = "some data here"
    .columns("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    .rows("1:1").font.bold = True
end with

'And so on...
```

You can't format data imported into an Access table, but you can add some formatting to an Access report or Form (I doubt you want to do this).